# "transaction do" without explicit receiver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

According to the docs, in Rails models, transactions are made on either classes descending from `ActiveRecord::Base` or any instance of such a class. Some blog posts on the subject list the following alternatives:

- `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do`
- `User.transaction do`
  User descends from ActiveRecord::Base
- `@user.transaction do`
  @user is an instance of User
- `self.class.transaction do`
  within any model.rb where self is e.g. User
- `self.transaction do`
  within any model.rb where self is e.g. an instance of User)

However, I'm missing another variation on this list: How about just `transaction do` within model.rb?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def foo
    transaction do
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Am I right to assume, that the `self.` is not really necessary since in the scope of a model instance method, self is always the model instance by default?

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct and inline with option 5 presented just above that.

Comment: The docs don't really state if there is a difference between `model.transaction` and `model.class.transaction`. It could be that the instance method is just a proxy to the class method.

Comment: @max That is exactly what it is the instance method is `def transaction(options = {}, &block); self.class.transaction(options,&block); end` [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb#L306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby the implicit recipient in an instance method is always the instance:

```
class Thing
  def foo
    inspect
  end
end
```

---

```
irb(main):026:0> Thing.new.foo
=> "#<Thing:0x007fde95955828>"
```

> Am I right to assume, that the self. is not really necessary since in
>   the scope of a model instance method, self is always the model
>   instance by default?

There is always an implicit recipient (self) in ruby. What it is depends on the context. In class methods its the class. Its "main" (the global object) if you are not in a class or module.

```
class Foo
  inspect
end
# => "Foo"

def foo
  inspect
end
# => "main"
```

You only have to explicitly use `self` where there is a need to disambiguate (like for example `self.class`). But there are many situations where it can help the readability of your code.

All of the options above are pretty much functionally equivalent:

- `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` connects to the DB for that environment from `database.yml` or `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]`.
- `User.transaction` or `class.transaction` can be used if you want to have different connections per model class or just don't like typing. All it really does is `connection.transaction(options, &block)`.
- The instance level `self.transaction` or `@user.transaction` just proxies to the class method. All it really does is `self.class.transaction(options,&block);`